# How to extract data to list in Prolog?

Tags: list, prolog

I have an array `L` of some type, I'm trying to extract the data to an array, for example:

```
L=[day(sunday),day(monday)]
```

to

```
Target=[sunday,monday]
```

Tried using `forall` and searched for related questions on Prolog lists.

```
extract_data_to_list(L,Target) :-
    member(day(Day),L),
    length(L, L1),
    length(Target, L1),
    member(Day,Target).
```

Current output:

```
?- extract_data_to_list([day(sunday),day(monday)],Target).
Target = [sunday, _5448] ;
Target = [_5442, sunday] ;
Target = [monday, _5448] ;
Target = [_5442, monday].
```

Desired output:

```
?- extract_data_to_list([day(sunday),day(monday)],Target).
Target=[sunday,monday]
```

Comment: You mean you're just trying to copy your list? And show your `findall` attempt.

Comment: Dont think it's a copy `[day(sunday),day(monday)]` to `[sunday,monday]`

Comment: Right, sorry I wasn't paying close attention! Use `maplist`. Define `day(day(D), D).` then use `maplist(day, L, Target)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an ideal problem for `maplist`:

```
day_name(day(DayName), DayName).

dates_daylist(Dates, DayList) :-
    maplist(day_name, Dates, DayList).
```

Maplist applies `day_name` to each corresponding pair of elements in `Dates` and `DayList`.

Answer (score 3):

This is an ideal problem for `library(lambda)` for [SICStus](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/sicstus/lambda.pl)|[SWI](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/file_details/lambda/prolog/lambda.pl):

```
maplist(\day(N)^N^true, Dates, Daylist).
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple other ways you can do this, just in case you're wondering.

```
?- findall(D, member(day(D), [day(monday), day(tuesday)]), Days).
Days = [monday, tuesday].
```

The trick here is that you can use `findall/3` to drive a simple loop, if the `Goal` (argument 2) uses `member/2`. In this case, we're unifying `day(D)` with each item in the list; no further work really needs to happen besides the unification, so we're able to "tear off the wrapping" just with `member/2` but you could drive a more complex loop here by parenthesizing the arguments. Suppose you wanted to change `day` to `day-of-week`, for instance:

```
?- findall(DoW, (member(day(D), 
                 [day(monday), day(tuesday)]), DoW=day_of_week(D)), 
           Days).
Days = [day_of_week(monday), day_of_week(tuesday)].
```

Making the goal more complex works, in other words, as long as you parenthesize it.

The second trick is specific to SWI-Prolog (or Logtalk, if you can use that), which is the new [library(yall)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=yall):

```
?- maplist([Wrapped,Day]>>(Wrapped=day(Day)),
          [day(monday),day(tuesday)], X).
X = [monday, tuesday].
```

`library(yall)` enables you to write anonymous predicates. `[Wrapped,Day]>>(Wrapped=day(Day))` is sort of like an inline predicate, doing here exactly what @lurker's `day_name/2` predicate is doing, except right inside the `maplist/3` call itself without needing to be a separate predicate. The general syntax looks something like `[Variables...]>>Goal`. This sort of thing was previously available as `library(lambda)` and has been a feature of Logtalk for many years.

Comment: Some remarks... The general syntax is `{Context...}/[Variables...]>>Goal`. Is worth to remark, because what has driven the introduction of library(yall) was the inefficiency of library(lambda), due to the *inverted* semantic about captured context.

Comment: Your findall-version has so many limitations. You really should mention them.

Comment: @false You have an answer, you mention them.